# How do I find a light on dark font?

Tags: fonts, contrast

I'm working on building a sea trading game, with a number of ports that you visit. Right now I am in the very early stages of making the game, using very primitive graphics. Today, I assigned names to each city, and display those names by the city, as below.

There's a few things that I'm going to do with the text, including center it, have it above or below the port, and possibly some other stuff that I haven't fully figured out yet. But the first problem I'm tring to manage is using a font to achieve better contrast. If at all possible, I would like to use the native text functions, which uses TrueType Fonts and OpenType Fonts. The typical way I've seen people address this question of visibility is with a light on dark, or dark on light, font, with essentially two colors. I've never seen a font like that, and I'm having difficulty finding one. What exactly am I looking for to achieve this? Or do I need to do something more drastic, that I'm not seeing right now? I would be more than happy with just a term for the font. For reference, I'm looking for something like the font at the end.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the key is to use a drop shadow or stroke around your text so it can show up on any background, that's how the provided screenshot handles it.

Comment: So am I then resigned to making a custom font? Ideally I would like to use an existing one, free or even reasonably cheap, and not have to mess with such things... But, well, if that's what I've got to do...

Comment: It depends what you're building your game with. On the web for instance it's trivial to add something like this, but at that point I think this question trends away from graphic design and more on tech support for whatever software you're using.

Comment: It's using Unity, for whatever that matters, but I am looking for a general solution, should I encounter such a problem again...

Comment: Just draw your text twice - first at (x+1,y+1) in black, then at (x,y) in your own favourite color. (That is assuming `+1` is a one-pixel offset in your game engine.)

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto a general solution would be too broad, because the solution does change depending on the software. The best general solution is to simply find a way to create contrast, which as per my previous comment is often done via stroke or drop-shadow.